# R, ggplot: Change line type between 2 x axis factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a plot with geom_line, and I want to change line type (solid to dashed) from a point to another point as in the picture.

my data frame look like this:

```
'data.frame':   33 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ pta.simnum      : int  2 2 3 3 5 5 8 8 15 15 ...
 $ dose            : num  100 100 200 200 400 400 700 700 1400 1400 ...
 $ group1          : chr  "arc" "nonarc" "arc" "nonarc" ...
 $ group2          : chr  "ei6" "ei6" "ei6" "ei6" ...
 $ pta.target      : num  0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5 1 1 2 2 4 4 ...
 $ pta.prop.success: num  0.925 0.935 0.925 0.935 0.925 0.935 0.901 0.904 0.901 0.904 ...
 $ toxic           : chr  "nontoxic" "nontoxic" "nontoxic" "nontoxic" ...
```

The idea is I want to illustrate non toxic dose and toxic dose in two types of line from low to high MIC of bacteria.

And this is my code:

```
graph.pta <- ggplot(data = pta.40, aes(x = as.factor(pta.target), y =  as.numeric(dose), group = group2, color = group2)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(data = filter(pta.40, toxic == "nontoxic"), size = 1,aes(linetype = "dashed")) + 
  geom_line(data = filter(pta.40, toxic == "toxic"), size = 1,aes(linetype = "solid")) +
  facet_wrap(~group1) 
graph.pta
```

and the result as shown in picture with these warning lines:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

I want to change line type from y value for each group according to the picture below however, the dashed line did not appear.

[image]

I suppose the result is not as expected since x axis is in factor, but the point I want to change to dashed line lies between two factors.

Is there any ways to plot this figure with my idea?

Thank you.

PS: I added part of my data as below:

```
structure(list(pta.simnum = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 
15L, 15L, 29L, 29L, 57L, 56L, 112L, 110L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 19L, 14L, 36L, 26L, 71L, 50L, 141L, 98L), dose = c(100, 
100, 200, 200, 400, 400, 700, 700, 1400, 1400, 2800, 2800, 5600, 
5500, 11100, 10900, 100, 200, 100, 300, 200, 500, 400, 900, 700, 
1800, 1300, 3500, 2500, 7000, 4900, 14000, 9700), group1 = c("arc", 
"nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", 
"arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", 
"arc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", 
"nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", "arc", "nonarc", 
"arc", "nonarc"), group2 = c("ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", 
"ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", "ei6", 
"ei6", "ei6", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", 
"ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", "ei8", 
"ei8"), pta.target = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 
8, 8, 16, 16, 32, 32, 0.125, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16, 32, 32), pta.prop.success = c(0.925, 0.935, 
0.925, 0.935, 0.925, 0.935, 0.901, 0.904, 0.901, 0.904, 0.901, 
0.904, 0.901, 0.902, 0.9, 0.9, 0.958, 0.958, 0.933, 0.92, 0.933, 
0.909, 0.933, 0.901, 0.926, 0.901, 0.915, 0.9, 0.91, 0.9, 0.908, 
0.9, 0.904), toxic = c("nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", 
"nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", 
"nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "toxic", "toxic", 
"nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", 
"nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", 
"nontoxic", "nontoxic", "nontoxic", "toxic", "toxic")), row.names = c(NA, 
33L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I have tried to take 'linetype' outside the aes but the result remains the same

Comment: I just edited my post. Please find it above. Thank you

Comment: The data you added don't actually make the plot.  There are 20 points in the posted dataset and at least 28 in the data that makes the plot above (it's difficult to tell whether there are distinct points for `ei6` and `ei8` below 2 for `nonarc`.

Comment: I have edited my post. Its the data i used to make the plot

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an option, you have only 1 point in some cases so lines would not work. You can try with points based on conditions to color them:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- pta.40 %>%
  mutate(Line=ifelse(dose>=6400 & group2=='ei6' & group1=='arc',1,
                     ifelse(dose>=7400 & group2=='ei6' & group1=='nonarc',2,
                            ifelse(dose>=7900 & group2=='ei8' & group1=='arc',3,
                                   ifelse(dose>=8200 & group2=='ei8' & group1=='nonarc',4,5))))) %>%
  mutate(pta.target=factor(pta.target,levels = sort(unique(pta.target)),
                           ordered = T))

#Plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = pta.target,
                      y =  as.numeric(dose),
                      group = group2,
                      color = interaction(factor(Line),group2),
                      linetype=factor(Line))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~group1)+
  labs(color='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Duck. Thank you but the point I want to change depends on the y axis. I want to change, for example, from the dose >= 6400 to dashed line wit "ei6" in "arc" group. There for the x axis value of this point will lie between 16 and 32 (not from 16). So basically, it is more like changing type line from a random point in plot

Comment: @QuanTruongAnh So the cutoff is 6400 right?

Comment: yes. Cutoff for"ei6" and "arc" is 6400. "ei6" and "nonarc" is 7400. "ei8" and "arc" is 7900". "ei8" and "nonarc" is 8200". I have total 4 cutoffs

Comment: @QuanTruongAnh Please adjust the code by yourself the data you shared is limited. Follow the filter strategy on your real data. Let me know how we can help if necessary.

Comment: Hi Duck. The data i shared is the full data used to draw the graph. I have tried to filter the based on cutoffs, creating a new variable to filter but it did not work. if you have any idea to plot this, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: @QuanTruongAnh I have added an option for you. Lines will not work as you only have one point so connections can not be done. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's  rather old question, but hopefully still helpful to you or others on the internet to be answered.

To correctly get the dashed and solid lines portrayed, you need to stack them correctly. In ggplot geom_layers stack on top on the previous.

Therefore, we start with the dashed lines.

```
p1= ggplot()+ 
geom_line(aes(as.factor(pta.target), as.numeric(dose), 
group=interaction(group1, group2)),size=1,linetype="dashed", data=pta.simnum)+
facet_wrap(~group1)
```

[image]

The last step is lay on top the lines that match you criteria. You want the solid lines to stop after pta target of 16. You can make a seperate dataframe or filter within a ggplot command as follows.

```
p1+ geom_line(aes(as.factor(pta.target), as.numeric(dose),
col=group2, group=interaction(group1, group2)), size=1, 
data=filter(pta.simnum, pta.target<16))
```

[image]

Let me know if this is what you meant